# In Android Studio a View knows where a function is but doesn't access it for some reason?

Tags: android, android-studio, file, class, kotlin

I'm simply trying to edit a View's text using the following code:

```
class FeedbackActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    fun submitReview(view: View)
    {
        val textToAdd = "It works"
        val textView = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Submit)
        textView.setText(textToAdd).toString()
    }
}
```

So, I create a file to store the class, let's call it rightOne.kt, set it as the declaration folder, and for some reason, the

```
android:onClick="submitReview"
```

"submitReview" appears in red, because it doesn't know where the declaration is, but when right clicking on the Go To -> Declaration or Usages, it actually takes me to the file.

So, if I put the class in another file that's already created and in use for something else, let's call it wrongOne.kt, it actually recognizes properly, the Go To shows both declarations, and the code works as intended. However, I do not want the class to be in that file for organization purposes. Is this a basic common issue or did I somehow mess up the entire thing?

EDIT: Tried to change some things, absolutely nothing happens, not even the println(). I thought Kotlin was supposed to be adopted by Google as Android's main development language, there's no documentation on this anywhere. For now, I just want to do something as simple as taking text from the Views and storing them in a variable.

```
class FeedbackActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_feedback)

    val rating = findViewById<RatingBar>(R.id.ratingBar2)
    val review = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.textInputLayout)
    val submit = findViewById<Button>(R.id.Submit)

    submit.setOnClickListener {
        println(rating.numStars)
        println(review.text)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If your project is open-source, please attach your link.

Comment: Note that `android:onClick` has been obsolete for years. Beyond that, what do you mean by "set it as the declaration folder"? And, what does your entire layout file look like (in particular, what `tools:` attributes do you have)?

Comment: It is not open source.

Comment: If its obsolete, why does it still work tho? But well, guess that explains why it's all going wrong. And by that I mean when you right click a piece of code and it offers suggestions on what to do.

Comment: Any chance you can provide the rest of the activity.

Comment: Hey, sorry for taking so long. I've added an edit to the post, I just don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `Clean Project` and `Rebuild Project` in the build tab. You could also try `sync Project with Gradle files`.

This is a legacy approach to handling clicks, it will only work in Activities and not fragments. You can set the method onClick in the fragment XML but the method would need to be in the Activity code.

The reason why this was the recommended solution at one point was that apps only used Activities. Now the dev team recommends apps use a single Activity with multiple Fragments. Could you imagine if you had to store all of your apps onClick methods one Activity it would be chaos.